# Subscription Based In App Purchase

Tags: iphone

Hello All
In one my application i want to implement InApp purchase,

But after study InApp Purchase apple document,

i have some confusion that which model is used in my current requirement,

Below i am trying to explain my requirement,

1) this is a newspaper application for iPad,

2) There is a 30 days subscription,

3) If i am install application in one device ex. iPAD1 and subscribe for 1month and now i want to install same application
in my other device iPAD2 my application should be working normally till end date.

Which model is appropriate for my requirement,

Comment: I have no experience on this, but I would reason that your in-app purchases are linked to your Apple ID account, therefore, you should be able to get the subscription status for an account, independant on which device is used.

Comment: So, to re-itterate; you want your customers to pay a small one-time activation fee for enabling to use the same subscription on other devices with the same Apple ID?

Comment: Yes, i want to provide one month free subscription.